# JavaScript Differences between Mobile iOS and Android Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I have been trying to google around for a few days to find some kind of answer, but is their a difference between how iOS mobile devices understand JavaScript, vs Android?

I currently have some code that works as expected on Android (Chrome/Edge), and on Windows (Chrome, Edge, IE 8). But once we get to iOS devices, it doesn't work as expected.

I also tried to see if I could find an emulator for iOS mobile, or just downloading the mobile Safari browser, but wasn't able to find one (that didn't have a cost related to it).

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it was related to the selectors in the code not being completed - Chrome got it, but safari didn't.